# При использовании статичного ip адреса вылазит ошибка с DHCP

Tags: ip, dhcp

хочу поставить статичный ip адрес на компьютере(Windows 10 домашняя, сейчас стоит динамический ip адрес), при смене ip адреса вылазит ошибка.
[image: То что хочу получить][image: сама ошибка][image: введите сюда описание изображения] Ранее на другом компьютере ставил и все было нормально, а на этом... И да, если ставить ip адрес, который сейчас подобран самой системой, то все работает, ровно до первого отключения от сети.

Comment: Вы у роутера посмотрите, какой предел адресов выделен для DHCP, а какой для статических. Кажется .117 это вы ссоритесь с DHCP роутера.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, разве предел адресов каждый раз меняется ? Ранее компьютером было выделено 116, недавно 117 (этот как раз таки я поставил как статичный, первое время работало, но после отключения компьютера от сети, интернет перестал работать), сейчас компьютер выделил 118, но так как я ленивый и не хочу все принтеры и ПО перепривязывать на другой ip, нужно решить этот вопрос.

Comment: Когда вы вручную поставили себе адрес .117 то другое оборудование использующее DHCP например мобильник получит от роутера такой-же адрес .117 и произойдёт конфликт адресов. То-есть ни мобилка ни вы ничего не получите. По-этому ещё раз намекаю : покажите диапазон адресов в роутере для DHCP.

Comment: Если роутер умный вроде mikrotik то проще выделенный адрес сделать фиксированным. Если не умный, то вручную прописать в роутере в статическое назначение адресов свой MAC адрес сетевой карты с адресом который не конфликтует с диапазоном DHCP. Или в крайнем случае у себя для сетевой карты в Винде фиксированное значение поставить.